# When I upload my CSS file to my website the website is ignoring all styling options for my h3 tag

Tags: html, css, web

My CSS file is not being read when I upload it. No styling at all only certain parts. If I open the developer tag in google chrome only half of the css code comes up. Why is my website being selective and not picking up all of the code?

Opening the developer tag in Chrome I only see this:

```
 body {
    background-color: #A9A9A9
    }

.ob {
  display: block;
}

#gamebox {
    position: static;
    width: 99.6%;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;                  /* using a flexbox here */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
```

As you can see some items are missing...

I have made a really basic subdirectory page here using this code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #A9A9A9
}

.ob {
  display: block;
}

#gamebox {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#title {
  color: grey;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: 3px 2px black;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="webnamecurveball.css">

  <title>
    Website name - Curveball
  </title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #A9A9A9">

  <h3 id="title" style="text-align: center"> Curveball </h3>

  <div id="gamebox">
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0" width="550" height="400">
       <param name=movie value="curve-ball.swf">
       <param name=quality value=high>
       <param name="menu" value="false">
       <embed src="curve-ball.swf" quality=high menu="false" 
       pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" 
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="550" height="400"> </embed></object>
  </div>
</body>
```

I expect to see a grey title at the top of the page with shadows. This is how it shows up when I open the file locally. However on the website the title comes up as pain text.

Comment: Did you try removing the inline style from the `<h3>` tag and adding it back to the .CSS file ? Also, prefer using classes over IDs on such elements like `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc

Comment: Was the old CSS file also named "webnamecurveball.css"? Production web hosting and browsers are aggressive in caching css files. If they where not the web would slow to a crawl. Try closings the browser and re-opening it. You may need to delete the old CSS file on the web host and reload it to convince the server the file is indeed new, (believe it or not I have one of these aggressive caching hosts - it is fast).  And, give the css file a new name for each production release ... Especially if the hosting has or takes advantage of distributed hosting in high traffic situations.

Comment: Wayne I would say that's a good shout! I just had another look at the css file in dev tools and it turns out it is the old one and no matter how many times I delete it/replace it or whatever it wont change to the new release. I will use a new release names from now, which btw works a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have the answer to this question. The problem is to do with aggressive caching as explained by Wayne above. The best possible solution is to publish a new css file every time you publish an update. E.g. from **webnamecurveball.css** I could update the css file and rename it to **webnamecurveballUPDATE1.css**

This has worked for me. Effectively I have edited the old file and renamed using save as. It is important to make sure that the html files take account this new update or the corresponding pages will remain the same.